# openfda results in spl_patient_package_insert_table not rendering HTML correctly

Tags: openfda, html

I'm accessing the spl_patient_package_insert_table data in the https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json endpoint.  The HTML returned in this field is not rendering correctly in a browser.  Does this require any CSS or other formatting to display correctly?  See attached screen shot. Please advise.  Thank you.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That field contains raw text and is not intended to be viewed with any CSS, although it may be easier to read by downloading and post-processing it.

Regards,

Violet Wren, openFDA Tech Lead